# Why Do We Associate Quadratic Forms To Symmetric Matrices Rather Than Upper Triangular Matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $k$ be a field, for simplicity assume that $\operatorname{char}(k)\neq2$, or even assume that $k=\mathbb{C}$. Given a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $k$, we can associate quadratic forms over $V$ to symmetric $\operatorname{dim}(V)\times \operatorname{dim}(V)$ matrices with coefficients in $k$.

For example, if we have a form like
$$
q(x,y)=3x^2+y^2-2x^2+4xy-xz
$$
then we have a corresponding matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Is there a specific reason for associating symmetric matrices to quadratic forms? We could as well use upper triangular matrices, so to the form $q$ above we can associate
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
I understand that the space of upper triangular matrices is isomorphic to the space of symmetric matrices. But why do we favour symmetric matrices?

Comment: One reason is that we often wish to treat bilinear forms on a given vector space $\Bbb V$ more generally, i.e., bilinear forms that are not necessarily symmetric in its entries, and the symmetric bilinear forms correspond (via any basis of $\Bbb V$) to symmetric matrices. On the other hand, any quadratic form (when $\operatorname{char} k \neq 2$) determines a *symmetric* bilinear form via polarization.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is that the quadratic form associated with **any** matrix $A$ is equal to the quadratic form associated to its **symmetric part**. To prove this, first consider that any matrix can be written as the sum of symmetric and anti-symmetric matrices as follows

$${\bf{M}} = {1 \over 2}\left( {{{\bf{M}}} + {\bf{M}}^T} \right) + {1 \over 2}\left( {{{\bf{M}}} - {\bf{M}}^T} \right) = {{\bf{M}}_S} + {{\bf{M}}_A}$$

Next, observe that

$$Q = {{\bf{x}}^T}{{\bf{M}}_A}{\bf{x}} = {\left( {{{\bf{x}}^T}{{\bf{M}}_A}{\bf{x}}} \right)^T} = {{\bf{x}}^T}{\bf{M}}_A^T{\bf{x}} = {{\bf{x}}^T}\left( { - {{\bf{M}}_A}} \right){\bf{x}} =  - {{\bf{x}}^T}{{\bf{M}}_A}{\bf{x}} =  - Q\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,Q = 0$$

and finally

$${{\bf{x}}^T}{\bf{Mx}} = {{\bf{x}}^T}\left( {{{\bf{M}}_S} + {{\bf{M}}_A}} \right){\bf{x}} = {{\bf{x}}^T}{{\bf{M}}_S}{\bf{x}} + {{\bf{x}}^T}{{\bf{M}}_A}{\bf{x}} = {{\bf{x}}^T}{{\bf{M}}_S}{\bf{x}} + 0 = {{\bf{x}}^T}{{\bf{M}}_S}{\bf{x}}$$